# Azure AD - Keycloak - Kibana Single-Sign on (SSO) User/Group Role mapping

Tags: azure-active-directory, single-sign-on, kibana, keycloak, roles

I have setup Single-Sign on (SSO) using keycloak and saml/OpenID broking between a web application (using Kibana for testing) and IDP Azure AD.

Created few users and groups in Azure AD. Also configured attribute mapping to map the user/group roles from Azure AD to keycloak by following the below link,

https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/getting-groups-from-azure-active-directory-idp/590

I need to map the same user/groups roles to Kibana application as well. My requirement is while a user logs into Kibana using the Azure AD - Keycloak Single-Sign On authentication, he should be able to login using the same Azure AD user/group privileges, So there is no need to create separate user/group roles in Kibana.
Is it possible to configure it? Please suggest.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/mapping-roles.html , possibly? You need to map the users privilege's somehow to roles in Kibana.

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to look into my answer? Any updates?

Comment: Hi Allen, Thank you for your suggestion. But i have one question? The authentication pipeline is Azure AD - Keycloak - Kibana, where Kibana authenticates with Azure AD via Keycloak. And i am using docker based Opendistro ELK. So how can i inherit roles from Azure AD to Kibana via keycloak?

Comment: Hi did you have a chance to check my answer? Is it what you want?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is [group claim](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/hybrid/how-to-connect-fed-group-claims#configure-the-azure-ad-application-registration-for-group-attributes).

For group claim, you could add the users into different security Groups and include Groups claim in your token. You just need to modify the "groupMembershipClaims" field in application manifest:

```
"groupMembershipClaims": "SecurityGroup"
```

Then the token will contain the Ids of the groups that the use belongs to like below :

```
{
  "groups": ["{group id}"]
}
```

[App role](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-add-app-roles-in-azure-ad-apps) can implement the same thing for you.